# Sending ArrayList to server not working with AsyncHttp

Tags: android, post, arraylist, android-async-http

```
HttpAsyncRequest request = new HttpAsyncRequest(
                               MapsActivity.this, 
                               Constant.BaseUrl, 
                               HttpAsyncRequest.RequestType.GET, 
                               new MarkerParser(), listener);
request.addParam("array",arr);  //this is not working
request.execute();
```

I want to send arraylist of latlng to the server i am using http request but we can only send string through that . How to send arraylist of latlng ?

Comment: What library is that exactly?

Comment: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ this is the library i am using @MatiasOlocco

Comment: Why aren't you using `RequestParams` as the docs say?

Comment: And I also don't see that class in the library, are you using the last version? I would recommend you to switch to a more maintained library, like [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: 1. when i long click on map the marker will set on the map and so on i make  more markers and it becomes array of latlng which i want to send on server.RequestParams needs key value but i dnt have any key value in my case i just have an arraylist of latlng which i want to send on php server

Comment: my whole project is now using this library so i cant switch to Retrofit library now @MatiasOlocco

Comment: then, what version is it?

Comment: latest version 1.4.9

Comment: But I cannot see that class in that version (in github at least). I see this:  `AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();` what am I missing?

Comment: @MatiasOlocco i find a way to do this work i posted in my answer. check that

Comment: but that is not optimal, I dont understand where you got that class. In the docs it says what I am going to post below.

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

> this is how i passed my arraylist of latlng to JSONARRAY and then converted into string and then i sent to server.

JSONArray pointsinjsonarray=new JSONArray();

```
                    for(int i=0;i<arraylistofmarkers.size();i++) {
                        try {
                            pointsinjsonarray.put(i,arraylistofmarkers.get(i));

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

pointsinjsonarray.toString();

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you are getting that class (maybe it is your own...), as I stated in my comments. In the docs it says that you should do the following:

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("array", arr);
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
//listener is an instance of AsyncHttpResponseHandler
client.get(Constant.BaseUrl, listener, params);
```

Source: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/